# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities in TestNG

Tags: selenium, grid

I am facing error "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities"  while executing grid in firefox browser.

Selenium version:3.14.0 , Geckodriver : 0.23.0 , firefox version : 63.0

[Grid code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQdCn.png)

In my code : 
Error is thrown in this line of code: 
d = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), obj1 );

Comment: Update the question with the Hub and Node startup commands and logs and the error trace logs for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through this link to check the compatibility of gecko driver,selenium and firefox version. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
And if it matches write the following code it helped for me.

```
FirefoxOptions fo = new FirefoxOptions();
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
fo.setProfile(myprofile);
```